# PHP SoapClient Doesn't Retrieve WSDL with Client Certificate

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Other similar questions have not helped me resolve this.

I have to retrieve a WSDL file using a client certificate + private key combination from my webserver calling another external SOAP API.

```
$wsdl     = 'https://www.example.com?wsdl';
$endpoint = 'https://www.example.com';

$sslContext = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$options = [
    'local_cert'                => '/var/www/combo.pem',
    'passphrase'                => 'Pass1',
    'cache_wsdl'                => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY,
    'trace'                     => 1,
    'stream_context'            => stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'ciphers'           => 'RC4-SHA',
            'verify_peer'       => false,
            'verify_peer_name'  => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        ]
    ])
];

try{
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '..domain..' : failed to load external entity "..domain..?wsdl"**

I tried numerous settings and none of them made any difference to this response. I tried no settings, empty array.

What has worked:

- Establishing a raw connection via CURL, so the certificate file is fine
- Retrieving WSDL information from SoapUI, so the WSDL destination is correct and the certificate file was okay

phpinfo() returns SoapClient is enabled, OpenSSL is enabled. What else could I try or check?

Comment: You could try loading the WSDL over simple `file_get_contents` to ensure that it can be loaded

Comment: @NicoHaase 1) I loaded the file through SoapUI. It can be loaded. 2) I'm not sure if file_get_contents can use a client certificate file

Comment: `file_get_contents` can use the very same `$context` you've creted in your script. Ensure that the WSDL can be loaded after all to make sure that the problem is in any way connected to SOAP and not to networking / certificate problems

Comment: @NicoHaase Could not have done this with file_get_contents, the value was always false. I managed to load the wsdl file by downloading it from SoapUI. I still can't connect to make a request.

Comment: Well, `file_get_contents` yields `false` if the request fails. This means: if even that fails, you have a serious problem to connect to that server. On the other hand, this means you don't necessarily have a SOAP-related problem

Answer (score 1):

SOAP error could come from invalid character encoding or maybe some HTTP header missing like 'User-Agent' when you query the remote server.

Try to adding User-Agent to options like the sample below.

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHP_Embedded_Soap_Client'
    )
);
```

PS: I would not recommend to strict ciphers to: RC4-SHA

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment this but based on others' suggestions of using `file_get_contents` and your reply mentioning that it returned false, I'm now kind of sure it's more of a connection problem. Please check followings:

1. It's obvious that your actual `$wsdl` value is different than what is posted but please make sure that `.com?wsdl` is not happening in your code. it should be `.com/?wsdl`.
2. Check your DNS settings. A lookup through dnslookup can help identify problem.
3. Make sure date & time setting of server is correct. It can lead to SSL errors.

If none of above helped. You might consider downloading WSDL content with other tools (such as `cURL`) and on different machines to identify the cause of problem.

Comment: Loading the WSDL file in SoapClient works. But I just can't connect, that's the thing, yeah.

Comment: @IvanIvković I remember I had a similar problem with a 3rd party API. They were not using SSL and once switched to SSL I was no longer able to connect albeit WSDL was accessible. After many hours of headache it turned out that problem was from their side. `location` attributes of `soap:address` tag in their WSDL was still referring to http instead of httpS. So please download WSDL manually and look for `soap:address location="https......" />`. Make sure it's httpS. If it wasn't then to workaround the problem, save a modified copy with httpS and load wsdl from file.